# How can I set the "preserveAspectRatio" attribute in a nested SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

We have a server generated SVG which cannot be modified and which needs to be displayed nested inside of another, larger, SVG.

It is necessary to modify the **"preserveAspectRatio"** attribute of the contained (inner) SVG to
**preserveAspectRatio="none"**
for it to display correctly.

The current approach is to define the nested SVG inside of a **DEFS** tag as follows:

```
<defs>
    <svg id="serverSetID"
        viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        >
        svg content here
    </svg>
</defs>
```

and then reference it as follows:

```
<use
    xlink:href="#serverSetID#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))"
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="200"
    height="200"
    />
```

Note: the nested SVG has a server generated ID attribute that is unique for that page.

If I leave out the **"#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))"** then it displays although not the way I want it to.

But if I include **"#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))"** then it does not display at all.

I have looked into other strategies such as directly including the code of the inner SVG within the body of the outer SVG without using the **DEFS** tag. But the problem with that strategy is that there does not appear to be a way to manipulate the **"preserveAspectRatio"** attribute since, as far as I can tell by experimentation and research, that attribute is not exposed to CSS in an SVG.

We are anxious NOT to use JavaScript for this because the page already has a LOT of very complex JS and we are trying to pare it down where possible.

Does anybody have any suggestions please?

PS. If I overlooked something (highly likely) or if **"preserveAspectRatio"** is indeed manipulable by CSS I will be humbly grateful for somebody to point out my error.

Comment: the defs svg should have a viewBox attribute and the preserveAspectRatio="none" Next you use the svg element with a use element where the width and the height attributes do not respect the svg's aspect ratio. What you are trying to do (i.e setting the value for the attribute in the url) is done for images or background images

Comment: Thanks for the input enxaneta :)   The problem is that the SVG comes from another subsystem on the server and cannot really be altered without breaking other stuff. So we need to be able to just set preserveAspectRatio="none" in that particular place. And, like I said, we would like to avoid using JS for this because the page already has too much JS which is proving really difficult to maintain and debug. The SVG actually SVG does have the viewbox attribute, I just left that out in the question to keep things simple. Hope thats ok. Thanks, Chris

Comment: you'd need to use an image to use SVG fragment identifiers. I don't think they work with use elements. Then images can only reference complete files so you can't use them with nested svg elements. Given the constraints you've set yourself I don't think there are any solutions.

Comment: Hi Robert Longson,  Thanks for your reply and time :) That may indeed be the case but here is the thing: I am able to use SVG Fragment Identifiers with the USE tag and they do display except that the preserveAspectRatio attribute is ignored. On the other hand if I use IMAGE tag then I CAN see the nested SVG but it is about 10 pixels wide (microscopic). Using a magnifying glass to examine the nested SVG I can see that it is displaying but just super small. So I obviously have a syntax error somewhere and I would probably need to see an example of how it is done I think. Thanks so much! Chris